# Combining isset and elseif statements

Tags: php, html

I would like to ask if this code is possible? What I want to happen is that it would only echo after pressing submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$z = $x + $y;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($z < "10") {
        echo "Higher!";
    } elseif ($z > "10"){
        echo "Lower!";
    } else {
        echo "You're right!";
    }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="number" name="x">
&nbsp;+&nbsp;
<input type="number" name="y">
<input type="submit" value="EQUALS">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must name some field "submit", because in the if statement you are checking if a field with the name submit is set. You dont have such field in your HTML. You can use the submit button. The only think you must do is put the attribute **name** with value submit in the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $x = $_POST['x'];
            $y = $_POST['y'];
            $z = $x + $y;

            if($z < 10) {
                echo "Higher!";
            } elseif ($z > 10){
                echo "Lower!";
            } else {
                echo "You're right!";
            }
        }
        ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="x">
            &nbsp;+&nbsp;
            <input type="number" name="y">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="EQUALS">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Velko Georgiev. It works. I'm just new to this PHP & MySQL world and reading from w3schools.